# How to change the line style of ECharts custom graph from solid to dashed or dotted

Tags: javascript, echarts

I created a custom graph using Apache [ECharts](https://echarts.apache.org) to draw a vertical line from the input data. Following [ECharts documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-custom) and some online examples, I was able to draw the line and custom it with color or width as per the MWE below.

My question is how to configure the line style as dotted or dashed. I searched extensively but could not find any options or documentation on that.

```js
const chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("chart"));

const render = (_, api) => {
  const start1 = api.coord([api.value(0), api.value(1)]);
  const end1 = api.coord([api.value(0), api.value(2)]);
  const x1 = start1[0];
  const y1 = start1[1];
  const x2 = end1[0];
  const y2 = end1[1];
  const line = {
    type: "line",
    shape: {
      x1,
      y1,
      x2,
      y2
    },
    style: {
      stroke: "blue",
      lineWidth: 3
    }
  };

  return {
    type: "group",
    children: [line]
  };
};

const options = {
  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    interval: 1
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    interval: 1
  },
  series: [{
    type: "custom",
    data: [
      [1, 1, 3]
    ],
    renderItem: render
  }]
};
chart.setOption(options);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ECharts custom line</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.1.2/dist/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha256-TI0rIaxop+pDlHNVI6kDCFvmpxNYUnVH/SMjknZ/W0Y=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart" style="width: 50%; height: 200px; position: absolute; top:0; left:0"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

MWE: https://codesandbox.io/s/echarts-custom-vertical-line-442cv

Comment: You want todo something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56633946/11629088)

Comment: @kamleshparmar Many thanks, but the `markLine` way is not suitable in this case. I don't want extra lines because I already created my own render to draw the lines. The only configuration that I might have missed is to set the line style to `dashed` or `dotted`. I looked into `markLine` perhaps as the last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make custom dashed line in echarts. You need to pass `lineDash` to the graphic element object.

`lineDash` is [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) attribute of `line` defining the pattern of dashes and gaps. Pass the values of dashes and gaps in form of an number array.

```
const render = (_, api) => {
  const start1 = api.coord([api.value(0), api.value(1)]);
  const end1 = api.coord([api.value(0), api.value(2)]);
  const x1 = start1[0];
  const y1 = start1[1];
  const x2 = end1[0];
  const y2 = end1[1];
  const line = {
    type: "line",
    shape: { x1, y1, x2, y2 },
    style: {
      stroke: "blue",
      lineWidth: 4,
      lineDash: [2] // put dash, gap values here
    }
  };

  return {
    type: "group",
    children: [line]
  };
};
```